# How get data from table based on value from another table (sql, ADO.Net)

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql, ado.net

In example below I select data from table based on values from other tables. These tables have relationships between each other.

I wrote code in C# using ADO.NET and Linq in Visual Studio. Is there a better way to get data?

Get id from first table:

```
var positionID = (from p in db.Employees 
                  where p.FIO == FIO 
                  select p.Position_Id).First();
```

Get code from second table based on value from first table

```
var AccessCODE = (from p in db.Positions 
                  where p.Id == positionID 
                  select p.Access_Code).First();
```

Return data from third table based on value from second table

```
return (from p in db.AvailableModuls 
        where p.Access_Code == AccessCODE 
        select p.Available_Modul).ToList();
```

[Model diagram screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7J0J.png)

Comment: Well - do these methods work for you? Do they return the correct / expected data? Do they do their job quickly enough for your needs? If so: just be happy and move on !

Comment: Show your model. Looks like you have complicated things. I'm interesting in navigation properties.

Comment: I added a screen of model to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to write everything in single query:

```cs
var query = 
    from e in db.Employees
    where e.FIO == FIO
    join p in db.Positions on e.Position_Id equals p.Id 
    join m in db.AvailableModuls on p.Access_Code equals m.Access_Code
    select m.Available_Modul;

return query.ToList();
```

Note that joins are not needed if you have proper navigation properties.

Comment: Yeah, this is simplifying things. So that is generally the way? But what's the point having relationships beetween tables(or having navigations property) if at the end of the day you still get data separatelly from each table?

Comment: 1) Safer access to related entities, you can forgot join key and query will return invalid result 2) Queries are simplified 3) Migrations 4) *if at the end of the day you still get data separately from each table* - what does it mean? In current query you need relations.

Comment: ok, seems logical enough. What are you mean by "proper navigation properties"?

Comment: `Employee.Postition`, `Position.Module(s)`, something like that. Check documentation [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)